# Did the Community user make a mistake?

Tags: bug, community-user

Community deleted this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3977648/how-can-i-find-the-mass-of-the-pencil-cylinder/3977750#3977750

Yet, it certainly does NOT meet the criteria for deletion. What's happeing?

Comment: One could argue that Community **never** makes mistakes, it is *us* who make mistakes in interpreting the algorithms that govern it. (In this case the "mistake" is the omission of "deleting an account" rule from consideration.)

Comment: To put it another way, Rule #1 is, Community is never wrong. Rule #2 is, in case Community is wrong, see Rule #1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question asker deleted their account, and upon account-deletion, all negatively-scored content from that account is deleted.

So the question did meet the criteria for deletion, although not those for [roomba-deletion](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/roomba).

Comment: oh....................

Answer (score 7):

This is not a separate answer, just a tip to keep in mind with respect to users who delete their accounts, or their accounts are deleted.  I'd comment, but I plan to post an image, which I can't do in a comment.

When you see any user######, along with the ghost like avatar, you can know that the user no longer has an account.  Also, note that unlike users with accounts, one can not click on any links to the user's profile, because account deletion wipes it all out.

I add this just so in the future, you can recognize when @DanielFischer's explanation applies.

: [image]